# How do I make this ffmpeg command work on mac?

Tags: macos, bash, ffmpeg

Works on Linux but I have a mac for work. I need to replace `alsa` and possibly `x11grab` so it works on MacOS:

```
screencap() {
  file=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S`
  ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -thread_queue_size 64 -i :0.0 \
    -i /dev/video0 -video_size 128x72 \
    -framerate 60 -preset ultrafast ~/Videos/screencast-${file}.mp4
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve - for those of us who don't know ffmpeg but do know Mac.

Comment: record screen and audio with ffmpeg on a mac

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590500/ffmpeg-record-output-audio-for-mac) will help.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208721 You don't need any 3rd party app to screen record on Mac. This is really an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) which is why I asked what you are trying to achieve, not what you already think you need to do to achieve it.